# Convert div and script to single iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I used the website tsviewer.com to create an insertable piece of HTML code I can insert into my webpage that will display the status of my Teamspeak server. This is what it gave me. But this doesn't quite work in vue as I don't know where to place the scripts.

```
<div id="ts3viewer_1118023" style=""> </div>

<script src="https://static.tsviewer.com/short_expire/js/ts3viewer_loader.js"></script>
<script>
var ts3v_url_1 = "https://www.tsviewer.com/ts3viewer.php?ID=1118023&text=757575&text_size=12&text_family=1&text_s_color=000000&text_s_weight=normal&text_s_style=normal&text_s_variant=normal&text_s_decoration=none&text_i_color=&text_i_weight=normal&text_i_style=normal&text_i_variant=normal&text_i_decoration=none&text_c_color=&text_c_weight=normal&text_c_style=normal&text_c_variant=normal&text_c_decoration=none&text_u_color=000000&text_u_weight=normal&text_u_style=normal&text_u_variant=normal&text_u_decoration=none&text_s_color_h=&text_s_weight_h=bold&text_s_style_h=normal&text_s_variant_h=normal&text_s_decoration_h=none&text_i_color_h=000000&text_i_weight_h=bold&text_i_style_h=normal&text_i_variant_h=normal&text_i_decoration_h=none&text_c_color_h=&text_c_weight_h=normal&text_c_style_h=normal&text_c_variant_h=normal&text_c_decoration_h=none&text_u_color_h=&text_u_weight_h=bold&text_u_style_h=normal&text_u_variant_h=normal&text_u_decoration_h=none&iconset=default";
ts3v_display.init(ts3v_url_1, 1118023, 100);
</script>
```

Discord on the other hand gives a single line of code that is easily inserted and works perfectly.

```
<iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=261587898996883458&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The question is, how does one convert the one kind to the other kind? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to add the Javascript before the  tag of your
   website ends.

   2. important is than that you render an div which the right id

Here some example

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>VueJs Introduction</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js">
      </script>

      <script src="https://static.tsviewer.com/short_expire/js/ts3viewer_loader.js"></script>
<script>
var ts3v_url_1 = "[add here the whole teamspeaker snippet url]";
ts3v_display.init(ts3v_url_1, 1118023, 100);
</script>

   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
         <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
      </div>


      <div id="ts3viewer_1118023" style=""> </div>


      <script type = "text/javascript">
         var vue_det = new Vue({
            el: '#intro',
            data: {
               message: 'My first VueJS Task'
            }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have removed the tsviewer code in his full length because the list is public.
You should add him there **[add here the whole teamspeaker snippet url]**

Maybe you should also modfiy your post after it or change the url as an example.

Comment: Not sure how I can use that within the <template> </template> tags in my .vue file. It only fails to compile...